# What are some examples where dynamic typing is preferred to static typing?

Tags: typing, duck-typing, dynamic-typing, static-typing

Let's take a simple function that increments an integer:

**Static typing:**

```
function incrementNumber(int n) {
    n = n + 1;
}
```

**Dynamic typing:**

```
function incrementNumber(n) {
    if (type of n != int) {
        throw Error;
    }
    n = n + 1;
}
```

These achieve the same thing, but the dynamic approach is way uglier and longer because of the "type checking" that's required.

I've seen a lot of programmers use this approach and it makes me wonder what exactly are the benefits of a dynamically typed language, since most functions will need a parameter check like this?

Do you have any examples where dynamic typing works (or looks) better than static typing?

Comment: If you do type checking for dynamic typing, the purpose is lost. You should instead just be concerned about the fact that the `+` operator is defined for whatever type is comming in. So irrespective whether it is int, decimal or string it should work as long as they know how to do `+` operation, isn't it?

Comment: That's exactly why I was confused: type checking defeats the purpose of dynamic typing, but at the same time I saw a lot of developers doing it. So is it a bad practice?

Comment: It might be more about inadequate knowledge or novice programming rather than bad practice. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna check the data type before doing anything, it has no benefits.

Dynamic typing only makes sense when you know that a function exists or an operator can be applied but the compiler don't know it until runtime. Or to create objects without definig its properties.

Comment: That's exactly why I was confused: type checking defeats the purpose of dynamic typing, but at the same time I saw a lot of developers doing it. Is it just "wrong" to approach dynamic typing that way?

Comment: That's right! Type checking when working with dynamics is wrong because it doesn't take the advantages of dynamic typing.